# Can I create database tables automatically in Laravel like Django's 'python manage syncdb'?

Tags: php, django, laravel, syncdb

I came from Django(Python) background and these days I'm working on a project which is based on Laravel(PHP).Do I have some option like generating database tables automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, using the [Schema Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/database/schema) and [Migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/database/migrations).

First you need to install the migrations table to the DB:

```
$ php artisan migrate:install
```

then create a migration

```
$ php artisan migrate:make create_users_table
```

this will create a PHP file in `application/migrations`. You may now edit it to have the settings you want, i.e.

```
<?php 

class Create_Users_Table
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->text('about');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

and execute it using

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

Every time you change the database structure you'll have to create a new migration and execute it afterwards.

Say you want `users` to have a new column `hometown` instead of `phone` you'd create a new migration

```
$ php artistan migrate:make users_table_add_hometown
```

and edit the new file to contain

```
<?php 

class Users_Table_Add_Hometown
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->string('hometown');
            $table->drop_column('phone');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->drop_column('hometown');
        });
    }

}
```

You now have two migrations, one creating the table and one modifying it.

The `artisan migrate` command is smart enough to only execute migrations that are new to the system. So if a collegue of yours comes home after a long vacation and there were a few new migrations it will automatically only import the ones that were created after he left.

Comment: One more thing.When there is some error in the definition of create table,the table gets created into database but that wont drop(I have to go to mysql to drop it manually) when I rollback the migration.Any Ideas?

Comment: I have added the (not very well documented) ability of `up()` and `down()` migrations.

Comment: Also, it is important that you do not remove the dates from the migration filenames. They decide the order in wich they are being executed.

Comment: How do models fit into the picture here?