# Migrations - automatically create database

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I'm pretty new to Laravel. I made a to do application as a school assignment. We have to use migrations to create our database.

I created 2 tables using migrations. My questing is: if you run the project for the first time on your pc, is there a way that the database is automatically created?

Because at this moment, I have to create the empty database first (manually in phpmyadmin) before running the migrations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123888/can-i-create-database-tables-automatically-in-laravel-like-djangos-python-mana ?

Comment: @Crembo, no my questing is not how to generate tables automatically. I want to know there is a possible way to generate the **database** AND tables automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you can do with SQL is possible in Laravel. So yes:

```
DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE your_db_name');
```

However you might not be able to do this in a migration because of the `migrations` table that's needed (although I'm not sure about this)

You could check [this post about using a command to create a new db](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27815295/1903366)